# How to display UnitLength in string?

Tags: swift3

In Swift 3, is there a way to display UnitLength type in a string? It doesn't want to convert to string.

I'd like to display the unit letters.

Comment: do you want to get the character count of a string

Comment: For yards, it is "yd". For meters, it is "m". I want to get those values as strings.

Answer (score 4):

To get the symbol of a specific UnitLength as a string:

```
let fathomsSymbolString = UnitLength.fathoms.symbol
// returns "ftm"
let micrometersSymbolString = UnitLength.micrometers.symbol
// returns "µm"
let inchesSymbolString = UnitLength.inches.symbol
// returns "in"
```